# Creating afterware with Express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Is it ok to create in Express route both middleware and "afterware"?

For example:

```
router.get('/:id', requireAuth, getById, verifyAuth);
```

In middleware - `requireAuth` - the middleware validates the JWT

In afterware - `verifyAuth` - the afterware validates if the user received information that was created by them/addressed to them.

Or should I validate everything in the service before responding to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `app.use()` or `app.all()` and declare separatly your `'/id'` route.

Comment: thats not the question, i'm already doing it.. the question is about how to implement afterware validation, in the service / in the route somehow